# readEntity affected by json_class?

Tags: jackson, jersey-client

Does the "json_class" attribute have some special meaning?  I have 2 get/post sets and that is the only signficant difference in the json.  The first set worked great.  I was able to use:

```
MyResponseClass mrc = client
                    .target(urlWithParams)
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("access_token", accessToken)
                    .get()
                    .readEntity(MyResponseClass.class);
```

The second set won't work unless i break into 2 parts (ie read into Reader and then map to object). The only significant difference I see is the first attribute in the second json is always "{"json_class":"Message","broadcast":false,"content":"post from java 1","created_at":"2013-08-14T12:31:03-05:00","deleted":false,"....}

```
 java.io.Reader reader = client
                    .target(urlWithParams)
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("access_token", accessToken)
                    .get()
                    .readEntity(java.io.Reader.class);       

THEN I can parse
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();        
   MyResponseClass response = mapper.readValue(reader, MyResponseClass.class);
```

But if I use the code from the first set it throws a "MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html; charset=utf-8, ..." exception.

Comment: Your error message suggests that you have wrong media type: "text/html" is NOT JSON. Other than that, you are missing details; does not work how? As to `json_class`, I am guessing that Jersey client adds that for some reason.

Comment: If it wasn't json then would the readEntity to Reader still work?  I don't think so.  When I print the reader object's contents it looks like perfect json (validates as ok).  The only thing at all 'different' about it is the json_class tag, but maybe that is a red herring.

Comment: You may want to read more about JAX-RS: yes, it would work. In first case, you ask lib to decode content, and if media type is "text/html" it absolutely and positively will not try JSON decoding (that would make no sense would it?). But if you ask for a `Reader`, you are given "raw" input, even if it's allegedly 'text/html'.